How to Listen for External Link Clicks in React Native globally?
I'm currently working on a React Native project and I'm looking for guidance on how to handle external link clicks within the app. Specifically, I want to be able to detect when a user clicks on a link that leads outside of the app (e.g., a link to a website) and show a Popup/alert before they visit the link.
Could someone provide a detailed explanation or code example of how to achieve this functionality? I'd greatly appreciate any insights or pointers in the right direction.
I attempted to check using Linking.addEventListener('url', handleUrl); in the main navigator, but I couldn't observe the listener being triggered. Additionally, I experimented with AppState.addEventListener, which did trigger, but I couldn't ensure that it only triggered when the user clicked on a URL.

Where does the link come from? As in, do you get it from an API and render it on the screen? And how are you opening the link?

The link can be from the API or it may be static inside the app, I open with Linking.openURL("https://www.google.com/"); @sj_959

If you are using Linking.openURL, I think you can write a custom hook this way: const useLinkCaller = () => {   const launch = (link, isExternal) => {     if (isExternal) {       Alert.alert(         'Warning',         'You are about to be redirected to an external link',         [           {             text: 'Abort',             onPress: () => {},           },           {             text: 'Proceed',             onPress: () => Linking.openURL(link),           },         ]       );     } else {       Linking.openURL(link);     }   };   return { launch }; };
